# Is collection.findOne({query}) not supposed to return the document itself?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I see a lot of tutorials/guides using `collection.findOne({query}).field` to get a value of a field in the document that is returned, but for me that doesn't seem to work and I wonder why. I did figure out another way to do it though. See below:

```
var rank = function(id) {
  // My way of doing it
  collection.findOne({ _id: id }, function(err, doc) {
    console.log(doc.score); // Prints the actual score
  });

  // How some tutorials do it
  var score = collection.findOne({ _id: id }).score;
  console.log(score); // Gives a TypeError (Cannot read property 'score' of undefined)
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> // How some tutorials do it

Those tutorials are likely using mongodb's shell, not node.js api. The shell's api looks similar (all the same words, `findOne`, etc.), but it doesn't use callbacks. Shell's `findOne` does return the document inline.

Comment: Sounds logical. I guess it must be that then. Thank you!